# How to select date and time from devextreme calendar in cypress

Tags: cypress, chai, devextreme, mochawesome

I want to select date and time from devextreme data time widget and where this data entered this field is locked.

**DevExtreme Calendar**
[image: DevExtreme Calendar and Time Control]
**Calendar Control HTML**
[image: Calendar Control HTML]
**Time Control HTML**
[image: Time Control HTML]

Comment: Can you add some information on what you've tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I want to select date and time from this date/time widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `<input>` for each time value on the form.

The first is hidden but has the value see `<input type="hidden" value="4">` and the second is for up/down control see `<input inputmode="decimal"...`.

To change the value directly, use `force:true` on the hidden `<input>`

```js
cy.get('dx-timeview')
  .find('input:hidden')
  .type('6', {force:true})
```